# DotNetNuke 5.2 Source - How to: Setup IIS 7 to Compile Source & Test the Site

Tags: sql, iis, iis-7, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

The answer to this may be a link to a good tutorial, but I've been unable to find one and it's getting rather frustrating.

I'd like to dive into the source code of DotNetNuke 5.2 which I have downloaded to a folder. I've opened up the solution that ships with it and it opens & compiles just fine.

**What are the recommended steps for:**

- Setting up the database for this
  source/compiled version of DotNetNuke?
- Configuring IIS 7 (on the local
  machine) to run/serve the site?

(Windows 7, VS2008, SQL-Server-2005, DotNetNuke 5.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FOr the setup you will follow the standard installation process, using the /website folder as the root for the configuration within IIS.

I have an [installation tutorial](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/276/pageid/138.aspx) on my blog that you can use, the specific tutorial is for 5.0.0, but the installation process is the same.  The short order process is as follows.

1. Create a database and SQL user for the database, giving them DBO permissions
2. Setup a virtual directory in IIS that points to the /website folder of your dnn installation
3. Grant the ASP.NET worker process account full permissions to the /website folder
4. Navigate to the /install/installwizard.aspx page, follow the instructions and set the database values for what you specified in number 1 above.

**NOTE**: the use of a source version of DNN for production use is not recommended, additionally it is my personal recommendation to not modify the source, unless you are truly willing to accept that future upgrades might not be possible due to your modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Mitchel. I'm ordering your book on Amazon!

Comment: No problem!  Good luck!  If you have any questions feel free to post directly to my forums, I seem to catch some of the DNN stuff faster there..

Answer (score 2):

**Expanding on Mitchel's Answer:**

1. Create a database and SQL user for the database, giving them DBO permissions
2. Go into DNN/Website folder. Copy release.config and name the copy web.config
3. Setup a virtual directory in IIS that points to the /website folder of your dnn installation
4. Open the solution and compile the project
5. Grant the ASP.NET worker process account full permissions to the /website folder (NETWORK SERVICE)
6. Had to give users group read/write/modify access to the entire website folder otherwise I got some errors about file access. This is more than is necessary but it worked.
7. Navigate to the /install/installwizard.aspx page, follow the instructions and set the database values for what you specified in number 1 above.

Edit: This is as of version 5.2 available 2/25/2010

Comment: FYI the copying of release.config is NOT needed when using installwizard.aspx  The default web.config (unless it got removed from the package) should be fine.

Comment: Well my legacy install worked fine (install.aspx). However, when I went back for practice to reinstall and document the process, I used the InstallWizard.aspx. This caused an incorrect entry to be inserted into the PortalAlias database table. There are various methods for correcting it for various people, but I ran into failure after failure until I simply ran this code on my DB Server: update portalalias set HTTPAlias = 'localhost/dnn1' where portalaliasid = 1

Comment: Mitchel is correct. It appears that renaming the release.config to web.config is only needed if the legacy installer is used.

Comment: @Mitchel the source package doesn't include a web.config...  am I missing something?

Comment: @bdukes - mine did I believe, but regardless, using the install wizard worked without any other changes.

Comment: @bdukes - I believe that the Install Wizard generates a web.config (at least that's my understanding)